# Free Paint with Layers for OS X 10.5

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-paint

I am looking for a paint program for OS X that can handle the major formats out there with transparent layers and is free. (Windows formats: ICO, ANI, CUR support  plus.)

Please provide link to download and also why you like the program.

I do not like GIMP. I am not looking to buy anything because I'm using a (long-term) borrowed MacBook.

**EDIT:**

Gimp does not have shape tools like paint or Paint.NET. That is why I dislike it.

To clarify: There is no "Square" or "Circle" tool. There is no "Rectangle with Rounded corners" tool.

Comment: just to reclarify: you do not consider 'select-a-shape-and-then-fill-it' as 'shape-tool', right?

Comment: nope. That can't do rounded off rectangles, btw.

Comment: it can: http://bit.ly/5TWSUe .. and by using the 'fixed size' option for the round and rectangle you can as well achieve 'circle' and 'square'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What don't you like about The GIMP? That's pretty much the defacto open source standard.

I haven't used these, but FYI...

http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/seashore/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a good one for Mac, but you could always run Paint under VMWare/Parallels/VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

took a look at [seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/) ?

alternately [gimpshop](http://www.gimpshop.com/download.shtml) uses a slightly different ui from gimp if that's the issue

Comment: Using Seashore. Also lacks shape tools, but alas... Gimpshop kept crashing. I'm not gonna bother with it.